# asp.net button click w/ javascript "are you sure?" prior to post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a asp:button that will fire a delete and want to have a client side javascript are you sure pop-up prevent any accidents.

whats the javascript to handle this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add the javascript to the OnClientClick() event of the button... the key is to return false if you want to cancel the event.  If you return false, the OnClick will not fire.

```
<asp:Button id="DeleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
            OnClick ="delete_clickhandler" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to?');" />
```

Alternately, you can call a method in javascript

```
<asp:Button id="DeleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
            OnClick ="delete_clickhandler" 
            OnClientClick="return MyDeleteConfirm();" />
```

Where MyDeleteConfirm() does something more elaborate, but returns false if you don't want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (the accepted answer did not)

```
<asp:Button id="DeleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) return false;">
</asp:Button>
```

Comment: Strange that the code I posted didn't work for you... what you have _should_ be more complicated than necessary.  Also, the point of my code is to suppress the `OnClick` event, and I don't see one on your button... how are you connecting the actual event to this button?  Wondering if that has something to do with it.