# How to set the priority of events in a buttonclick?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here I need to call a javascript function first and after some time I need to call a c# function on the same button click event. Is it possible?

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBTNExportPPT" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0" 
 OnClientClick="JavaScript:exportCharts('JPG');" OnClick="imgBTNExportPPT_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/PPT_icon.png" />
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: In your code JavaScript function will be executed first.

Comment: Well what happens in the current case and what is the shortfall as of now ?

Comment: the javascript is executing before c# code but it waits to execute completely till i click anything on the popup which appears bcoz of my c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "after some time" you mean something like "after 3 seconds an action has to be executed" then you can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) `setTimeout(functionToCallAfterIntervalToWait, intervalToWait)`

If you want to call a server side method you can use an ajax call inside functionToCallAfterIntervalToWait - leave a comment if you need help with the ajax call

For an example on how to call your asp.net server method from javascript see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx) blogpost (google call asp .net server method from javascript for more examples/tutorials)

Assuming you are using jQuery you would write (using [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax( { 
url:"yourAspxPage/NameofTheMethodToCall", 
data: {"nameOfParameter": valueOfParameter}, 
success: function (data) {
//this function will be called after the server side function executes successfuly
});
```

If  you want that this function call is made after other client side operations make sure to write below (after) the other commands .

Comment: I don't understand your scenario - you have your javascript code which you use to initiate an action server side (this may be ajax or PageMethods (which is still ajax) if asp.net) - now on the server you do some work and then you return.... On both ajax/PageMethods you can specify an "onSuccessCallbackFunction" that will allow you do process the data returned from the server side function. What exactly is your challenge?

Comment: am new to asp.net..how to call that method using ajax call..any sample

Comment: how to execute server side processing only after client side processing is complete

Answer (score 2):

Javascript functions are executed client side. C# function are executed server-side. Without further temporization or async request, the client-side onClick handler function will be executed before the server-side onClick handler function.

If I get you, the images you want to export are available after the client-side processing, aren't they? So, execute server-side processing only after client-side processing is complete.

Without AJAX? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219240/asp-net-button-click-w-javascript-are-you-sure-prior-to-post-back).

Here's some code:

```
<script>
  function exportCharts(input)
  {
    //business here
    if(business works)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

</script>

  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBTNExportPPT" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0"  ImageUrl="~/Images/PPT_icon.png"
    OnClientClick="return exportCharts('JPG');"
    OnClick="imgBTNExportPPT_Click" />
```

The server-side imgBTNExportPPT_Click handler will be executed only if exportCharts returns true.

Comment: yes perfect..how to execute server side processing only after client side processing is complete

Answer (score 1):

Why not call the Server side method through an Ajax call

You could place this at the end of your JavaScript method

Comment: am new to asp.net..how to call that method using ajax call..any sample

Comment: how to execute server side processing only after client side processing is complete